# After enabling depth testing in OpenGL, my entire screen is blank (reverts to clear color) - why?

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

In my C++ graphics application using OpenGL and GLUT, I want to enable depth testing via

```
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
```

However, these two lines of code clear my screen, which is now just the clear color. I was wondering why.

I am just supposed to have a few primitive solid spheres and cubes.

Comment: Enabling blending does not enable depth testing. The two are independent (though blending to achieve transparency can be related to it).

Comment: As the answerer below noted, I had forgotten to clear my depth buffer per every redisplay. Sorry, I'm new to OpenGL, so I really appreciate the support. And thanks, I understand the difference between blending and depth testing now.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sounds like you've forgotten to clear the depth buffer and are thus failing the depth test due to whatever preexisting garbage is in the depth buffer memory.  Try to add GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT to your glClear() call, like so:

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
```

Good luck!

Comment: What about the `glClearDepth` call to set what value to clear it to?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're also drawing between your Z near and Z far values after enabling depth testing.

Comment: If I remember correctly, if OP tried to draw something not between Z near and Z far, it wouldn't work regardless of depth testing. (Unless `GL_DEPTH_CLAMP` is enabled.)